# Looking for a Story about Knights with magical powers fighting for their kingdom

Tags: story-identification

There was a dark lord or something like it from another land that was threatening the kingdom.

A wise king decided to form an army of knights with magical powers. They started out with something between 5 and 10 knights, each with their individual powers, strengths and weaknesses. I'm pretty sure that it was a land split into many kingdoms, and the king of one of the kingdoms remembered a story from ancient times about an army of knight with magical powers that had defended the land. This king wants to rebuild such an army. He then send missives throughout the land seeking people with magical powers. This is how he got the first knights. I also remember that they came to this king at a young age. They were about 7 or 8 years old at their arrival. Types of magic included force, fire, telepathy, telekinesis, etc.. about all types of magic available.

After some years the army was starting to grow as they recruited more people with magical affinity.

At some point, the gods of this world even came into play to try and keep the balance between good and evil.

It was probably a French story.

That's all I can remember. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. I read this about 8 years ago and it seemed pretty new then. I'm pretty sure it was a series of novels.

Comment: Unfortunately this is pretty generic; magical armies are not anything unique.  Knights makes me think of Codex Alera; your timeframe and a google search gives me Hero of Ages from the Mistborn trilogy; but both involve preventing apocalypse and very little balance.  Any details you can remember - especially the only characters you mention, the king and/or the gods - would be helpful.

Comment: mistborn series doesn't fit this at all.

Comment: There can't be that many instances of [knights with magical powers](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicKnight)...

Comment: @Himarm - magic knights -> Mistings, especially when they find the Atium; wise king -> Elend; god beings, gots those; plot doesn't match up, which I noted, but I've seen wilder fits on descriptions as vague as this.

Comment: @Radhil i understand you can compare these too, however, never in the book themselves are they referred to similar to knights, so its a huge stretch to go from 2 mistborn, and like 5 mistings, into a band of of magical knights. also atium is worthless to mistings, it only affects mistborns(and theres never more then 2-3 of these), or the rare atium consuming mistings which are only in the 4th book.

Comment: @Himarm - 3rd book, actually, which is the one that I mentioned, that's close to his timeframe (came out 2008).  I'm aware of the matches and mismatches, thank you.  What I can't find is something with an older feel (as written, this sounds a bit cliche, maybe Tolkeinesque?) around 2006-2008.  Maybe you can suggest one?

Comment: it sounds like the plot to the dragon quest games. >.> @Rocket can you elaborate of the type of magic there using, elemental, fire water ice ect, or a force like magic, anything? the type of magic really can narrow down the search

Comment: @Himarm Like i said in the question.. all knights had a unique ability.. either it was forc, fire, telepathic, telekinesic etc.. about all tye of magic were available. And when the gods comes in action it is incredible. I must read this story back.

Comment: @Himarm I've put some more details i just remembered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be the series called *[Les Chevaliers d'Émeraude](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Chevaliers_d%27%C3%89meraude)* (*[Knights of Emerald](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_Emerald)* in the English release)? There are 12 of those, plus the second series (the next generation?)

- Young knights with magical powers, with great variations in powers and abilities
- The knights come from all vassal / allies (Sapphire kingdom), most of the time young
- The first teacher was a mage that had worked with the gods, and a few knights met other mages.

This is a teen-level book (my girl of 10 is currently reading them; my boy of 12 left the series midcourse, speaking of overly powerful heroes), but they are in the adolescent section of our library

Comment: That is exactly it !!!!!!!! WOUUUUUUUHHOUUUUUUUUUU !!!!!

Comment: Oh now... this is gonna feel good reading thos once again :D THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!